# Qt creator and unwanted automatic prefix for a filename

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtestlib

How can I disable automatic "tst_"-prefix for a cc-filename, when creating unit test subproject in Qt creator?

[image: test case name]

[image: Unwanted prefix for a filename]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these setup wizards are created with a `json` config and templates, so they are pretty customizable.

Look in your QtCreator install folder in the following path: `share\qtcreator\templates\wizards\`. The Auto Test project wizard is in `autotest` subfolder.  I would make a copy of this folder and rename it. You could just edit the existing one, but it will probably be replaced at next Creator update.

You'll find a `wizard.json` file in there. At the top is an `options` array, and in there are templates for the file names.  You'll see the `tst_` prefix on a few entries.

```
        {
          "key": "TestCaseFileWithCppSuffix",
          "value": "%{JS: 'tst_' + value('TestCaseName').toLowerCase() + '.' + Util.preferredSuffix('text/x-c++src') }"
        }
```

Then you can simply delete the prefix and save the file.

For more gory details, see the QtCreator docs [Adding New Custom Wizards](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html).

**PS**. This might be obvious to some, but for completeness...

If you do copy the wizard to a new folder, I think you'll need to change one line in the json config, and want to change another.

```
    "id": "R.AutoTest",
    "trDisplayName": "Auto Test Project",
```

The `id` needs to be unique, and the `trDisplayName` probably should also be so you don't confuse it with the included wizard. The `id` also defines the sort order (the "R." is arbitrary, used for sorting). You can also delete the included wizard but again I think that would only last until the next QtC update. There's no other way to disable them permanently AFAIK.

Lastly I would consider putting my custom wizards in the user config folder as described in the "Locating Wizards" part of the docs (there will already be a ton of config stuff in that location, so it's hard to miss).